# Using the preposition For to indicate a purpose

Tags: grammar, idioms, prepositions

I am curious to know if the usage of "for" in the sentence below is grammatical?

> The reason why “socioeconomical understanding” is chosen as the umbrella section is *for* it to mediate the understanding of innovation in X industries. The following subsections are intertwined in their individual evolutions and implications for X industries.

PS: I am aware that there is a split among linguists concerning the usage of "The reason why". By extension, I am open to suggestions regarding reconstructing the paragraph.

Comment: I'd use 'so that it will/might' rather than 'for it to' in cases where a rewrite is probably unnecessary. Here, I'd rewrite.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why do you think a rewrite is necessary here? And, care to take a shot?

Comment: I'd just thank @J.R. Bye for his/her excellent suggestion. It's clearer and pithier.  But rewriting sentences and above is off-topic, as writing advice, on ELU; I can't decide whether to upvote or downvote his/her answer. And please keep questions within scope in future.

Comment: I assume you didn’t write this dreadful nonsense. Unless you really have to, I’d avoid reading it. But if you really want to know whether it is correct, do not accept comments as answers. That is not how this site works. Consider only formal answers that can be voted down and criticised, and judge them on evidence and argument, not on mere assertion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified." I believe that I highlighted a specific source of concern in the text: the dilemma regarding the usage of the idiom "The reason why".

Comment: While I find no problem with the use of *for*, I would personally replace ***for it*** *to mediate* with ***so that*** *it mediates*.

Comment: I believe I said that asking for a rewrite of a sentence / paragraph was off-topic. Who mentioned proofreading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of 'for' is acceptable as Kate commented. I'm sure the reason you are asking is because it sounds a little clunky. This is what I would do to simplify it.

*The umbrella section “socioeconomical understanding” was chosen to mediate the understanding of innovation in X industries. The following subsections are intertwined in their individual evolutions and implications for X industries.*

Hopefully this puts you on the path to a final structure.

Comment: It’s always nice to hear opinions, but answers on SE EL&U have to be supported by evidence or argument. How else is the poster or anyone else to know whether or not your opinion is correct? That is why I have flagged your answer as low quality.

Comment: @David Thank you for sharing your concerns. Do you happen to have a counter-argument?

Comment: @ÖzgürAkyıldız — I would add that my comment was intended to help JR Bye, who is relatively new to this list, and is valid whether or not I personally can answer your question.

Comment: I should have included a technical reference but sometimes that stuff gets in the way of a concise answer. I could have lead off with that and followed with my suggestion but I didn't think it was as important as giving the answer.